# How to change button size depending on device?

Tags: html, css

I have got a button on my website, which becomes tiny, when you visit it from mobile. I have tried a few things to fix this, but they failed to complete my objective.

```css
#generate {
  background-color: #FFAF19;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

#generate:hover {
  transition: .5s;
  background-color: #e59d16;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

#generate:active {
  transition: .1s;
  background-color: #e59d16;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  #generate {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #generate {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is how you're meant to do it. If anyone knows how to fix it, please help me.

(account-generator.tk is the hosted place with the button)

Comment: Do you have set viewport metadata - does your media queries take effect?

Comment: They do not work.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the button actually needs to be different on smaller screen sizes if you want it to increase in size. So change it in `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`.

Here is an example:

```css
#generate {
    background-color: #FFAF19; outline: none; border: none; color: white; border-radius: 10px; width: 200px; height: 50px; font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 25px; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -100px;
  }
  #generate:hover {
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #e59d16;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  }
  #generate:active {
    transition: .1s;
    background-color: #e59d16;
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    #generate {
      width: 200px; height: 50px; 
    }      
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #generate {
      width: 300px; height: 75px;  
    }
  }
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable auto-scale? Someone told me you can turn off a CSS element that automatically resizes the page.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">```

Comment: And your idea does not work. I have tested it.

Comment: Then we need more details for anyone to be able to help you further.

Comment: Do you want the website link? (http://account-generator.tk/)

Comment: You could add it to the question.

Comment: Also, should I set a min and max width/height?